# Fullscreen games locks desktop after minimizing (Bumblebee+Nvidia)

Tags: freeze, games, bumblebee, fullscreen

I have this problem on 3 Linux distros.

I run games in full-screen and after minimizing them,

1. The game freezes when I'm trying switch to other window,
2. Screen (and resolution) stays frozen until I turn off the game.
3. Then the screen switches resolution back and I can use other windows/programs again.

I have **Fedora** , my ntb uses **Bumblebee + Nvidia** drivers (installed through Fedora tutorial "[Bumblebee](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bumblebee)").

Basic recommended Rpm-fusion drivers isn't supported by my graphics card (**GeForce GT 730M**), even the official drivers by Ge-force though my card is in list of supported cards.

I can't have `xorg.conf` file, Gnome can't start with it. It looks like the game takes over the display and locks it.